# ¿Puedo forzar a Java para que utilice la hora GMT/UTC+0?

Tags: java, date, java-8, time

Estoy trabajando con las APIs de `Date` y `Time` de Java 8. En mi código me interesa coger la hora **GMT/UTC+0**, pero recoge la del ordenador que es **GMT/UTC+1**.

¿Puedo forzar `Java` a que haga esto sin necesidad de cambiar la hora de mi ordenador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo descubrí por mí misma.

Añadí esta línea en `VM arguments` de run configurations y ahora tengo GMT/UTC+0 en mi entorno.

```
-Duser.timezone=UTC
```

Answer (score 1):

Si usas Java 8 o superior bastaría con usar

```
Instant.now()   // Captura el momento actual en UTC
```

Si no, puedes usar usar estos métodos:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

//Local time zone

SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");

//Time en GMT
return dateFormatLocal.parse( dateFormatGmt.format(new Date()) );
```

Comment: No es esto lo que busco. Lo que quiero es que mi entorno tenga el mismo comportamiento que al modificar la hora desde la configuración de Windows. Instant.now() me da la fecha actual en GMT+0, no es eso lo que busco exactamente.

Answer (score 1):

Este código te debería devolver un Date con GMT+0 como tú quieres

```
private Date convertirAGmt(Date date){
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Date ret = new Date( date.getTime() - tz.getRawOffset() );

    if (tz.inDaylightTime(ret)){
        Date dstDate = new Date( ret.getTime() - tz.getDSTSavings() );

        if (tz.inDaylightTime(dstDate)){
            ret = dstDate;
        }
     }
     return ret;
}
```

fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599109/how-to-convert-a-local-date-to-gmt

Answer (score 1):

Para tomar la hora de una zona horaria distinta a la de tu país, debes setear en una instancia la zona horaria del lugar que necesites haciendo uso de la clase ZoneId, luego asignar a la instancia de la hora actual aquella ZoneId que seteaste al inicio; por ejemplo:

```
ZoneId idZona = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
LocalTime horaActual = LocalTime.now(idZona);
DateTimeFormatter formato = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
String horaFormateada = horaActual.format(formato);
System.out.println("La hora actual en Los Angeles es: " + horaFormateada);
```